# How can LLMs understand and perform meta tasks? (e.g. summarization)

Tags: large-language-models, text-summarization, prompt

I don't ask how to make it summarize xy but if it is known how a "LLM" understands and performs this meta task at all.

The same is true for prompts like "Be brief" or "Explain in a few sentences". Since this works, the LLM must actually have an understanding of text length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have to think that LMM are just next-token-predictors, so if you let it read a lot of text from the web/textbooks, probably they will learn that after "Be brief" there is a summarization of the text given before, which means to exclude certain words, to phrase stuff in a certain way and so on

You might also be interested in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.01066.pdf#:%7E:text=Transformers%20can%20in%2Dcontext%20learn%20linear%20functions.&text=Specifically%2C%20the%20trained%20model%20achieves,to%20generate%20the%20training%20prompts.)